# Node exceljs reading file

Tags: node.js, exceljs

So according to the offical documentation i should be able to read an excel document using:

```
    // read from a file 
var workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
workbook.xlsx.readFile(filename)
    .then(function() {
        // use workbook 
    });

// pipe from stream 
var workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
stream.pipe(workbook.xlsx.createInputStream());
```

I have the following document:

[image]

What i need to do is basicly to load each row into an object:

```
var excelObject = {competence1: '', competence2: ''}
```

And then save it into an array.

However the documentation doesnt give me more on how i might read from this file. It uses a variable called `stream` however this variable is not explained anywhere.

Does anyone know the plugin and know how i might achieve my goal?

Comment: I've never used the module but in the `.then()` callback, I assume you can access the data from the worksheet e.g. `workbook.getWorksheet("My Sheet").getRow(4).getCell(1).value` as per the docs. https://github.com/guyonroche/exceljs/blob/master/README.md

Comment: It looks like the stream example is for piping data into a workbook.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
var workbook = new Excel.Workbook(); 
workbook.xlsx.readFile(filename)
    .then(function() {
        var worksheet = workbook.getWorksheet(sheet);
        worksheet.eachRow({ includeEmpty: true }, function(row, rowNumber) {
          console.log("Row " + rowNumber + " = " + JSON.stringify(row.values));
        });
    });
```

Comment: filename is file path or what ? my file path is public/uploads/test.xlsx

Comment: `row.values` returning an array, is there any built in method to get it as a object (Key value pair)?

Comment: `sheet$.eachRow is not a function` function was deprecated or doesn't exist

Answer (score 8):

And in case you are using file as ArrayBuffer (for example file was read on client with FileReader.readAsArrayBuffer()), then to make it load with this lib you have to do the next:

```
    let workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
    let stream = new Stream.Readable();
    stream.push(file); // file is ArrayBuffer variable
    stream.push(null);
    workbook.xlsx.read(stream).then((workbook)=> {
         // get worksheet, read rows, etc
    });
```

Answer (score 6):

The below code snippet will help you to read the file sample.xlsx, which contains two columns 1. username 2. password.  and I'm trying to assert with Mocha(chai), to check the data type match.

```
var Excel = require('exceljs');
const assert = require("chai").assert;

var workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
workbook.creator ="Naveen"; 
workbook.modified ="Kumar";


workbook.xlsx.readFile("sample.xlsx").then(function(){
    var workSheet =  workbook.getWorksheet("one"); 

    workSheet.eachRow({ includeEmpty: true }, function(row, rowNumber) {

        currRow = workSheet.getRow(rowNumber); 
         console.log("User Name :" + currRow.getCell(1).value +", Password :" +currRow.getCell(2).value);
         console.log("User Name :" + row.values[1] +", Password :" +  row.values[2] ); 

         assert.equal(currRow.getCell(2).type, Excel.ValueType.Number); 
       //  console.log("Row " + rowNumber + " = " + JSON.stringify(row.values));
      });
})
```

Hope this helps somebody

Answer (score 4):

```
//Read a file
var workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
workbook.xlsx.readFile("data/Sample.xlsx").then(function () {

    //Get sheet by Name
    var worksheet=workbook.getWorksheet('Sheet1');

    //Get Lastrow
    var row = worksheet.lastRow

    //Update a cell
    row.getCell(1).value = 5;

    row.commit();

    //Save the workbook
    return workbook.xlsx.writeFile("data/Sample.xlsx");

});
```

Comment: Won't it be better to add some description as well?

Answer (score 2):

I was getting an error for .xls file. After trying all the permutation and combination, I converted the .xls file into .xlsx and it worked.

```
const Excel = require('exceljs/dist/es5');


const readExcel = async () => {

  //You can use the absolute path also
  let filepath = './genovaFile.xlsx';

  let workbook = new Excel.Workbook();

  await workbook.xlsx.readFile(filepath);

//You can use the index number also eg. 0 for selecting the sheet
  let worksheet = workbook.getWorksheet("sheet1");

   worksheet.eachRow({ includeEmpty: true }, async (row, rowNumber) => {

    console.log("row " + row.values);

   })

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Step1: Download exceljs module using npm

Step2: Use the following piece of code to read data from excel

```
import { Workbook, Worksheet } from 'exceljs';

public static async getExcelD(filename: string, column1Item: string) {
        let wb:Workbook = new Workbook();
        let datafile = path.join(__dirname, "../testData", filename);
        await wb.xlsx.readFile(datafile).then(async ()=>{
            let sh:Worksheet = wb.getWorksheet("Sheet1");
            for(let i=1;i<=sh.actualRowCount;i++){
                if(sh.getRow(i).getCell(1).value==column1Item){
                    data1 = sh.getRow(i).getCell(2).value;
                }
            }
        })
        return await data1;
}
```