# ExcelJS does not find given file

Tags: javascript, exceljs

I want to import an xlsx file into my website and based it on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28864652/node-exceljs-reading-file). However, whatever filename and path I put in, it gives me this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'F_OK')

The part in question looks like this:

```
const Excel = require('exceljs')
var workbook = new Excel.Workbook(); 
workbook.xlsx.readFile('spielplan.xlsx')
```

I have tried moving the file into different directories and using their paths, tried it from the directory itself, and have tried to give the absolute file path. Every time the same error mentioned above pops up.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Can you share your folders structure?

And remember the root of your JS project is the current path from your shell, so make sure you are calling it from the right place.

Try to specify the relative path this way as well:
`workbook.xlsx.readFile('./spielplan.xlsx')`

Comment: Folder structure currently looks like this: https://imgur.com/a/JVMMLBO

Comment: The relative path is from the root, have you tried "./pages/games/file.xmlx"?

Comment: I took a better look and seems you are using next.js, so you can move this file into the public folder, I believe it will solve your error.

Answer (score 0):

[image: attached image to describe dir]try this it worked for me,

```
    const fs = require('fs');
    const fullPath = fs.realpathSync('folder name in which file is/file.xlsx')
    let workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
    await workbook.xlsx.readFile(fullPath);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).